# How to determine if row I am clicking in Qtreeview has already been selected or not?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtreeview

I have a table in Qtreeview with multiselect enabled. When I click on one of the rows, how do I determine if it is already selected?

Comment: You could subclass and override the `mousePressEvent()` (or install an event filter for `MouseButtonPress`) and check whether the `indexAt(event.pos())` is in the `selectedIndexes()`.

Comment: So in vba you can do something like:                        
If List3.selected(List3.Listindex)=True then                                                                       I was hoping there would be something like that in PYQt5 but from what you are telling me I need to iterate through selectedIndexes() and compare with the current index?

Comment: `selectedIndexes()` returns a list of indexes, just use the basic python `in` operator: `if indexAt(event.pos()) in self.selectedIndexes()`.

Comment: Or: [`tree.selectionModel().isSelected(index)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#isSelected).

Comment: @musicamante trying to stay within pyqt5 and I think event.pos() is pygame module or am I mistaken?

Comment: @ScottCov with `event` I mean the argument of `mousePressEvent` or `eventFilter`. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html